# h2o java server remains in memory after R shutdown

Tags: java, h2o

I exited R and found h2o.jar remains in the background. Confirmed by checking H2OFLOW in localhost:54321, where I found the data frames from my last session. Is this expected? How to completely shutdown the java server?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is intended -- we wouldn't want to kill an H2O cluster with valuable models on it by accident (if R or Python crashed for some reason).  It makes more sense if you think about R/Python as a gateway to the H2O Cluster.

To shutdown the H2O server from R, type: `h2o.shutdown()` or `h2o.shutdown(prompt = FALSE)`.  You can also kill the associated Java process manually in the terminal if you've already exited R.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This makes sense now. I realize I could also do a shut down from H2OFLOW in a browser.